# Need Sub-category with main Category

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic

Currently I used the following codes for get WooCommerce product categories. But, I need sub-categories too. Also what is the way to remove `class="label-0"` from select options?

```
<?php 
        if(isset($_REQUEST['product_cat']) && !empty($_REQUEST['product_cat'])) {
            $optsetlect=$_REQUEST['product_cat'];
        } else {
            $optsetlect=0;  
        }
        $args = array(
            'show_option_all' => esc_html__( 'All Categories', 'woocommerce' ),
            'orderby'            => 'ID',
            'hierarchical' => 1,
            'class' => 'cat',
            'echo' => 1,
            'value_field' => 'slug',
            'selected' => $optsetlect
        );
        $args['taxonomy'] = 'product_cat';
        $args['name'] = 'product_cat';              
        $args['class'] = 'cate-dropdown hidden-xs';
        wp_dropdown_categories($args);
    ?>
```

---

```
<select name="product_cat" id="product_cat" class="cate-dropdown hidden-xs">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">All Categories</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="womens-fashion">Women’s Fashion</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="mans-fashion">Man’s Fashion</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="phones-accessories">Phones &amp; Accessories</option>
</select>
```

Comment: it should include children as well. are these empty? than you might want to add the attribute to show empty ones as well. and why are u creating an array and than add (taxonomy, name) and overwrite(class) values right afterwards..? i dont see an option for the level class, though.

Comment: I have children categories under `Man’s Fashion`. Can you please note here complete codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe your children are empty, if so, they will not show up by default. you have to set the `hide_empty` argument to `true`. plus i cleaned your array a little, first you create one, and than in the next line you add more arguments. keep your code clean..

```
$optsetlect = (isset($_REQUEST['product_cat']) && !empty($_REQUEST['product_cat'])) ? $_REQUEST['product_cat'] : 0;

$args = [
    'show_option_all' => esc_html__( 'All Categories', 'woocommerce' ),
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'class' => 'cate-dropdown hidden-xs',
    'value_field' => 'slug',
    'selected' => $optsetlect,
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
    'name' => 'product_cat',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
];

wp_dropdown_categories($args);
```

`echo true` & `orderby ID` is also default, so there is no need to set these. check the [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories) for further arguments. and since you change `value_field` you might check this here as well:

> **selected**
>       *(integer|string) (optional)* Which category ID is initially selected in the dropdown. The type of value should match the 'value_field', which is term_id by default. For example, if 'value_field' is set to "slug", then 'selected' will take a slug instead of an ID.

aka your $_REQUEST variable contains a slug, correct?!